# Type annotations for a dictionary that maps types to a list of instances of that type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In Python 3.11, I would like to create a class that holds a dictionary where the key is the type of a class and the value of that key is a list of objects of that type. The code:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")

class DictHolder:
  def __init__(self):
    self._things: dict[type[T], list[T]] = {}
```

run through pyright, complains that `Type variable "T" has no meaning in this context`. That makes sense, since `DictHolder` is itself not a generic class.  It is not parameterized on a single type, so it does not inherit from `typing.Generic[T]`. However, its private dict field is generic, as might be any properties or accessor functions that expose or interact with this generic dict.

What are the correct type annotations for the dictionary?

Comment: You seem to already understand the solution, why don't you make it generic?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It won't help. Generics don't work this way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried to explain why the class can't be generic; the reason I don't make it generic is because it's not a generic class, and making it so doesn't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I think I understand my confusion now. Can you elaborate a little bit on how you expect this to be used (e.g. a dummy accessor) and what you expect type checkers to be able to catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done; it's impossible to annotate a dictionary with per-element constraints. The solution is to annotate the dictionary to represent its mapping from types to objects, and then make the methods themselves generic.

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")


class TypeToObject:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._dict: dict[typing.Type, list[object]] = {}

    def add(self, obj: object) -> None:
        if type(obj) not in self._dict:
            self._dict[type(obj)] = []

        self._dict[type(obj)].append(obj)

    def get(self, obj_type: type[T]) -> list[T] | None:
        if (maybe_list := self._dict.get(obj_type, None)) is not None:
            return typing.cast(list[T], maybe_list)

        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tto = TypeToObject()
    tto.add(3)
    tto.add(1)
    tto.add(2)
    print(tto.get(int))

    tto.add("hello")
    tto.add("world")
    print(tto.get(str))
```

Note that in Python 3.12+, the `TypeVar` can be omitted, and `get` can look simply like:

```
    def get[T](self, obj_type: type[T]) -> list[T] | None:
        return self._dict.get(obj_type, None)
```

Comment: if you want to avoid `Any`, I guess you could use `dict[type[object], object]`

Comment: I think it's more important to avoid `Any` (or `object`, or anything overly general) in the method type annotations, and less important in the dict itself. It also seems unavoidable for the dict. Though, I'm not really sure what the practical differences are between using `object` vs `Any`?

Comment: Well, mypy and pyright will not allow `Any` if you use stricter options because `Any` basically means "don't type check this". It is meant as an escape valve to allow for gradual typing. For a concrete difference, if I have `x: Any`, then the type checker won't complain if you do `x.this_attribute_doesnt_exist`, you can do *anything* with it. `object` is the base type of all types. Anything can qualify as an object, but you can't do much with it

Comment: So: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=004d244134a5b3df3eccd2cc49d09b72

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes good sense!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a way to properly indicate that the dictionary keys will be types (classes), and the dictionary values will be lists of instances of those types. The issue with your current approach is that `T` is used as if `DictHolder` is a generic class, but it isn't. The type variable `T` indeed has no meaning in the context of `DictHolder`'s `__init__` method as it stands.

So to make this correct without making `DictHolder` a generic class, you don't need to use a type variable (`TypeVar`) in this case. Instead, you can use `type` and `typing.List` directly along with the `typing.Any` type to indicate that your dictionary can hold lists of instances of any type.

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Type

class DictHolder:
    def __init__(self):
        self._things: Dict[Type[Any], List[Any]] = {}
```

This annotation indicates that `_things` is a dictionary where each key is a type (`Type[Any]`) and each value is a list of instances of any type (`List[Any]`). This allows you to store lists of different types indexed by their types in `_things`.

However, this approach loses some type specificity (since we are using `Any`), but it's suitable for scenarios where the dictionary is meant to hold items of various types. Umm If you need more specific type checks when adding or retrieving items from the dictionary, you might need to implement custom methods in `DictHolder` that perform runtime type checks.

As far as I remember, type annotations in Python are mainly for static type checking and they do not enforce type safety at runtime. So, it's essential to ensure that the logic in your methods correctly handles the types as you expect.

Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Using `Any` isn't really a solution, it is essentially saying "don't type check this". And questions about "correct" type annotations are implicitly about using static analysis which the ecosystem supports.